# Kendo ui editor body background picker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

Is there a way to create a custom color picker to change the editor's body background color? I looked at the documentation and it seems that the palette is just available for font color and text background color, not body background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color of the editor using:

`$("#editor").data("kendoEditor").body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'`

All you need is to hook the `select` option on the color picker to set the editor's background color with the selected value.

```js
$("#picker").kendoColorPicker({
    value: "#ffffff",
    buttons: false,
    select: function(e) {
        $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").body.style.backgroundColor = e.value;
    }
});
```

See here for a sample: http://dojo.telerik.com/EYusEQ/2